# Is Join or Where clause approach more efficient in restricting result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I need to restrict a result set for a SELECT statement based upon Col1 have 1-to-many potential values. For example, I want to return all rows where Col1 equals a value of 1, 2, and 3.

So far I have two different approaches to restricting the result set:

Approach #1

```
Inner Join Table1 On (Table2.ColA=Table1.ColA) And (Col1=1 And Col1=2 And Col1=3)
```

Approach #2

```
Inner Join Table1 On Table2.ColA=Table1.ColA
Where (Col1=1 And Col1=2 And Col1=3)
```

Is one of these approaches preferred or is there an alternate approach that would be more efficient? The values are dynamic and passed to the stored procedure each time it is called.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: What do the query plans say? I personally prefer (and I think others would agree) approach #2, because the way it reads closely resembles what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Col1 can not equal 1 2 and 3 all at the same time.  1 != 2 != 3.  Also, there better not be a Col1 in both tables.

Comment: The actual query is quite complex and I'm just looking for the basic principle by keeping the example simple.

Answer (score 8):

### INNER JOINs

When dealing with an INNER JOIN, it doesn't matter if the filtration on the table being joined to follows the `ON` clause, or occurs in the `WHERE` clause -- it will produce the same result set.

### OUTER JOINs

But that's not the case for OUTER JOINs...
In an OUTER JOIN, if you specify filtration criteria in the `ON` clause -- the criteria are applied *before* the JOIN is made.  Here's an example:

```
     FROM TABLE_1 a
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 b ON b.cola = a.cola
                   AND b.col1 IN (1,2,3)
```

This can affect the result set drastically, compared to if the criteria had been specified in the WHERE:

```
     FROM TABLE_1 a
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 b ON b.cola = a.cola
    WHERE b.col1 IN (1,2,3)
```

### Conclusion

All that matters is that you:

1. Know the difference
2. Are consistent in your query structure

Answer (score 3):

It's not an issue of efficiency.  Your restrictions limit which rows will be returned; therefore they logically belong in the WHERE clause.

Comment: +1 - I think if you check you will find the query plans are the same, but the `WHERE` clause makes more sense and is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

A pre-scrubbed WHERE (subquery), but check the query plan for the difference:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   ...
JOIN   (select ... from table1 where col1 in (1,2,3) ) as Table1
ON     Table1.ColA = Table2.ColA
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description says "1, 2 or 3", so you'll want

```
Where (Col1=1 Or Col1=2 Or Col1=3)
```

or you could do this

```
Where Col1 in (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, the optimizer will produce the same query in the end.  I think filtering in the WHERE clause is more readable though, especially for inner joins.